# Flutter - 'title' or 'RaisedButton' are crossed

Tags: flutter, dart

I use vscode + flutter plugin. Why 'title' in BottomNavigationBarItem or 'RaisedButton' are crossed out by flutter?

```dart
BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.map_outlined), title: Text("help"))
```

[vscode screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WGph.png)

Comment: Raised button is crossed out as its deprecated use elevatedbutton instead and title is paramater to give title to navbaritem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are being **deprecated**, which means that the Flutter Team now recommends that you don't use them anymore, and gives you some alternatives.

For `BottomNavigationBarItem`'s `title` property, use the `label` property instead:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.map_outlined), label: "help")
```

and for the `RaisedButton`, now use `ElevatedButton`:

```
ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => null, child: Text("Click Me"));
```

Also, with the ElevatedButton styling has become a little different.

To style an ElevatedButton use:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () => null,
  child: Text("Click Me"),
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.green, etc....)
);
```